# Why won't RPScreenRecorder stopRecordingWithHandler work?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, wkwebview, replaykit

I am testing usability of a website and am using WKWebView in a native app.  The reason for this is so that I can use COSTouchVisualizer to show the touches, and RPScreenRecorder to record the interaction and the 'talk out loud' with the mic.

I have the following IBAction to start the recording:

```
@IBAction func startRecordSession(sender: AnyObject) {

    let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.sharedRecorder()

    guard recorder.available else{
        print("Cannot record the screen")
        return
    }

    recorder.delegate = self

    recorder.startRecordingWithMicrophoneEnabled(true) { (err) in

        guard err == nil else{
            if err!.code ==
                RPRecordingErrorCode.UserDeclined.rawValue{
                print("User declined app recording")
            }
            else if err!.code ==
                RPRecordingErrorCode.InsufficientStorage.rawValue{
                print("Not enough storage to start recording")
            }
            else{
                print("Error happened = \(err!)")
            }
            return
        }

        print("Successfully started recording")
        self.recordBtn.enabled = false
        self.stopRecordBtn.enabled = true
    }

}
```

Which seems to work with the printing Successfully started recording.

However, when the button connected to the IBAction to stop recording is pressed the following code should run:

```
@IBAction func stop() {

  let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.sharedRecorder()

  print("1. before the recorder function")// This prints

  recorder.stopRecordingWithHandler{controller, err in     

    guard let previewController = controller where err == nil else {
      self.recordBtn.enabled = true
      self.stopRecordBtn.enabled = false

      print("2. Failed to stop recording")// This does not prints

      return
    }

    previewController.previewControllerDelegate = self

    self.presentViewController(previewController, animated: true,
      completion: nil)

  }

}
```

But nothing happens except to print out the first log ("1. before the recorder function").  I get non of the other log statements nor do the buttons toggle their enabled status.

I know the IBAction is connected due to hitting the statement but no idea why I can't get the stopRecordingWithHandler to fire.

I am testing this on an iPad Pro 9.7" running iOS 9.3.

I am starting to wonder if it has anything to do with trying to record a WKWebView but would imagine that I would get an error if this was the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that if you were to set a breakpoint anywhere inside your `guard` statement (within `stopRecordingCompletionHandler`), it would not crash your program or enter the debugger because the `else` clause of your `guard` statement is never being called.

In fact, this is expected behavior. We would not expect the `else` clause to execute unless either controller is equal to `nil` and therefore cannot be bound to the constant `previewController` or `error` exists and therefore does not equal `nil`.

With `guard`, the only way the `else` clause will be called is if the specified conditions are **NOT** true. Your print statement in the `startRecordingWithMicrophoneEnabled` closure is being called because it is sitting outside of the `guard` statement.

So you just need to move some of that logic out of the `else` clause. You do still want to handle errors there though.

```
recorder.stopRecordingWithHandler{controller, err in     

      guard let previewController = controller where err == nil else {

          print("2. Failed to stop recording with error \(err!)") // This prints if there was an error

          return
      }
}

self.recordBtn.enabled = true
self.stopRecordBtn.enabled = false

previewController.previewControllerDelegate = self

self.presentViewController(previewController, animated: true,
  completion: nil)

print("stopped recording!")
```

### Guard

So just to be sure we're clear on the `guard` syntax, it's:

```
guard <condition> else {
    <statements to execute if <condition> is not true>
}
```

In your example, you're combining `guard` with optional binding and a `where` clause, to create the following situation:

- If `controller` is not `nil`, it will be bound to a constant called `previewController`.
- If it is `nil` then we stop evaluating , never create the constant `previewController`, and escape to the `else` clause, which must transfer control with a keyword such as `return`.
- If `controller` is not `nil` and our constant has been created then we will go ahead and check our `where` clause.
- If `where` evaluates to `true` (so if there is no error), we will pass the test and be done with the `guard` statement. **`else` will never be executed.**
- If `where` evaluates to `false`, we will execute the `else` block and **anything after the `guard` statement will not be called.**